# How to do section title in TableView if there is no sections in data from json?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, tableview

just like title says, I would like to categorize my data by some property which I get from json.
Here is example of my json:

```
{
"rows": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Trip to London",
        "status": "CURRENT",
        "companyId": 395,
        "approvedBy": null,
        "start": "2021-01-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2021-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "approvedAt": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2021-01-04T13:32:45.816Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-01-04T13:32:45.816Z",
        "services": "Flight"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have 3 states of my response, which is status: String in json response and possible values are: upcoming, current and previous. I would like to categorize my data by status property, if I get that trip is current, then put it under section title of current.

What I tried so far is this:

In ***numberOfRowsInSection***:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearching {
        return self.filteredData.count
    }
    return bookedTrips.count
}
```

In ***viewForHeaderInSection***:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: Cells.sectionTitle) as! TripsListHeaderCell
    if section == 0 {
        cell.configure(trips: "CURRENT")
    } else if section == 1 {
        cell.configure(trips: "UPCOMING")
    } else {
        cell.configure(trips: "PREVIOUS")
    }
    return cell
}
```

***EDIT:***
In **cellForRowAt**:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.tripInfo) as! TripsListDetailCell
    if isSearching {
        cell.configure(trips: filteredData[indexPath.row])
    } else {
        cell.configure(trips: bookedTrips[indexPath.row])
    }
    return cell
}
```

And if I return number 3 in function **numberOfSections**, I have my section titles displayed, but since I returned count in **numberOfRowsInSection**, everything is duplicated. What should I do to categorize my data by status prop from json, since I don't have 2D array so I could work with sections?

And of course, if there is better way how to write viewForHeaderInSection, which I am pretty sure there is, please give me advice.

I can post some screenshots if needed if my question is not properly written and its hard to understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: What about creating a `struct BookSection { let title: String, let books: [Book] }` to populate your UITableView? Just find a way (`reduce(into::)` etc. to convert [Book] into that? In `numberOfRowsInSection`, it's be `myBookSections[section].books.count`, etc. Ie: change your point of view, create the model you need, and create `init()` methods to change your current data into the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 : You need to create struct for Trip like as below

```
struct TripStruct
{
    var sectionName : String
    var tripArray : [TripModel] = [] // Here TripModel == Your Trip Model
}
```

Step 2 : You need to group data into section

```
var tripStructList : [TripStruct] = [] //Here this Global Variable
var filterTripStructList : [TripStruct] = [] //Here this Global Variable

let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: allTripArray, by: { $0. status }) // Here allTripArray == Your trip array from json
let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()
self.tripStructList = keys.map({ TripStruct(sectionName: $0, tripArray: groupedDictionary[$0]!)})
```

Step 3 : Set data in tableView delegate and datasoure method like as below

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return isSearching ? self.filterTripStructList.count : self.tripStructList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return isSearching ? self.filterTripStructList[section].tripArray.count : self.tripStructList[section].tripArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: Cells.sectionTitle) as! TripsListHeaderCell
    
    let sectionRow = isSearching ? filterTripStructList[section] : tripStructList[section]

    cell.configure(trips: sectionRow.sectionName)
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.tripInfo) as! TripsListDetailCell
    
    let sectionRows = isSearching ? filterTripStructList[indexPath.section] : tripStructList[indexPath.section]
    let row = sectionRows.tripArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(trips: row)
    
    return cell
}
```

Step 4 : Search your data

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    
    if searchText == ""
    {
        isSearching = false
        filterTripStructList.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    }
    else
    {
        isSearching = true
        
        let filterAllTripArray = self.allTripArray.filter({$0.tripName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}) // Here allTripArray == Your trip array from json
        
        let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: filterAllTripArray, by: { $0.status })
        let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()
        self.filterTripStructList = keys.map({ TripStruct(sectionName: $0, tripArray: groupedDictionary[$0]!)})
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: how would my cellForRowAt function look like with your implementation? I tried your solution, but keep getting errors index out of range, I have to take in consideration data from search. Probably cause I am already filtering in searchBar function, I am gonna send you my whole controller code if you are willing to look into it. I am still new to ios and I never worked with dictionaries. https://pastebin.com/ULfhjA3U  @Silversky Technology

Comment: Hello @iosguy I updated my answer with search functionality,Please look into it

Comment: thank you sooo much!! this works properly, I will retype everything from your answer so I can see where my approach was wrong and to learn more about dictionaries. One more thing, where should I put from your second step, third, fourth and fifth line? I can't put that as global, giving me error, yet I can't in viewDidLoad cause it can't reach scope to all functions? @Silversky Technology is it ok to just store that in numberOfSections function?

Comment: you have to put those line after you got all data from server